# JQuery problem with nested mouse events

Tags: jquery, events, mouse

I seem to be having a problem when using all 3 of these events at the same time.

I have a large div which have mouseup, mousedown, and mousemove bound to it. Inside of this large div, there is several smaller divs (which I would like to be clickable). I should add that the `clickable` element is a child of the larger div.

The problem is that the `click` event does not seem to be working. However, if I comment out the other mouse events, it works fine.

I am guessing there is some sort of conflict of events here, since a click is really a combination of mousedown and mouseup.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //Create tooptips for existing zones
                $('.oldBox').tipsy({
                    title: 'data-callrange',
                    gravity: 'sw'
                });

                var x1,y1;
                $('.openTab .img_container').live('mousedown', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();


                });

                $('.openTab .img_container').live('mousemove', function(e) {

                });

                //Process just created box
                $(document).mouseup(function() {

                });

                $('.oldBox').live('click', function(){
                    $('#mouse_pos').html('You clicked '+ $(this).attr('data-callrange'));
                });
            });
   </script>
```

Comment: It would be a big help to see the jQuery you think is causing the problem. Also a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the events on the parent `div`, you can check to make sure the clicked element (the event target) was in fact the parent div, and not the child div. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/AQWvc/) as an example.

In the event handlers for the parent `div`, use something like:

```
if(event.target.id == "i_am_a_big_div_with_three_events") {
    //Do stuff
}
```

And attach your click event to the child `div` as normal.